# Laravel 4 - Repository Pattern Testing with PHPUnit and Mockery

Tags: laravel, mocking, phpunit, repository-pattern, mockery

I'm working on an application for a client but am having trouble testing the repositories.

To bind the repository to the model I have the following code:

```
<?php

namespace FD\Repo;

use App;
use Config;

/**
 * Service Provider for Repository
 */
class RepoServiceProvider extends \Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $app = $this->app;

        $app->bind('FD\Repo\FactureSst\FactureSstInterface', function ($app) {
            return new FactureSst\EloquentFactureSst(App::make('FactureSst'), new \FD\Service\Cache\LaravelCache($app['cache'], 'factures_sst', 10));
        });
    }
}
```

The repository then extends an abstract class containing the functions from the eloquent ORM (find, where, all etc.). The code for the repository looks something like this:

```
<?php

namespace FD\Repo\FactureSst;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use FD\Repo\AbstractBaseRepo;
use FD\Repo\BaseRepositoryInterface;
use FD\Service\Cache\CacheInterface;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

class EloquentFactureSst extends AbstractBaseRepo implements BaseRepositoryInterface, FactureSstInterface
{
    protected $model;
    protected $cache;

    public function __construct(Model $resource, CacheInterface $cache)
    {
        $this->model = $resource;
        $this->cache = $cache;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve factures with the given SST and BDC IDs.
     *
     * @param int $sst_id
     * @param int $bdc_id
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
     */
    public function findWithSstAndBdc($sst_id, $bdc_id)
    {
        $return = new Collection;

        $factures = $this->model->where('id_sst', $sst_id)
            ->whereHas('facture_assoc', function ($query) use ($bdc_id) {
                $query->where('id_bdc', $bdc_id);
            })
            ->get();

        $factures->each(function ($facture) use (&$return) {
            $data = [
                'facture_id'   => $facture->id,
                'facture_name' => $facture->num_facture,
                'total_dsp'    => $facture->total_dsp(),
                'total_tradi'  => $facture->total_tradi()
            ];

            $return->push($data);
        });

        return $return;
    }
}
```

To test the calls to the database I'm using Mockery as calls to the database will be too long. Here is my test class:

```
<?php namespace App\Tests\Unit\Api\FactureSst;

use App;
use FactureSst;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
use Mockery as m;
use App\Tests\FdTestCase;

class FactureSstTest extends FdTestCase
{
    /**
     * The primary repository to test.
     */
    protected $repo;

    /**
     * Mocked version of the primary repo.
     */
    protected $mock;

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->repo = App::make('FD\Repo\FactureSst\FactureSstInterface');
        $this->mock = $this->mock('FD\Repo\FactureSst\FactureSstInterface');
    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
        parent::tearDown();
        m::close();
    }

    public function mock($class)
    {
        $mock = m::mock($class);
        $this->app->instance($class, $mock);
        return $mock;
    }

    public function testFindingBySstAndBdc()
    {
        $this->mock->shouldReceive('where')->with('id_sst', 10)->once()->andReturn($this->mock);
        $this->mock->shouldReceive('whereHas')->with('facture_assoc')->once()->andReturn($this->mock);
        $this->mock->shouldReceive('get');

        $result = $this->repo->findWithSstAndBdc(30207, 10);
        $this->assertEquals($result, new \Illuminate\Support\Collection);
        $this->assertEquals($result->count(), 0);
    }
}
```

As you can see in the test, I'm just trying to call the function and make sure that the functions are chained properly. However I keep getting an error saying:

> App\Tests\Unit\Api\FactureSst\FactureSstTest::testFindingBySstAndBdc
>   Mockery\Exception\InvalidCountException: Method where("id_sst", 10) from Mockery_0_FD_Repo_FactureSst_FactureSstInterface should be called
>    exactly 1 times but called 0 times.

Please can somebody help me to understand why this isn't working and how to fix it. Sorry that the code is in French, the application is for a French client.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as though you are mocking the repository itself when you really should be mocking the dependencies of that repository, namely `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` which is where you are going to be hitting the database.

Change `setUp()` so that it creates a mock object of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` and then have it inject that mock object when your repository is being instantiated.

```
public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    $this->mock = m::mock('Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model');  // Or better if you mock 'FactureSst'
    $this->app->instance('FactureSst', $this->mock);
}
```

This is a little confusing because you state the abstract class contains the ORM methods but when you are calling those methods, you are calling them on the injected `Model` dependency, not on the abstract class.  This is likely where the confusion lies.

Also, if your models extend `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`, it's often better to just inject your model into the repository and not `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`.  This way, you also get to take advantage of any relationship functions you have setup in your model inside your repository.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. As you said, I have an abstract class that contains the ORM methods, so I should be making calls to the model which I will have to change.

I will check it out Tuesday when I go back to work, thanks for the reply

Comment: Just checked it out, by calling the abstract repo methods and not the model, the tests are working. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken this line

```
$result = $this->repo->findWithSstAndBdc(30207, 10);
```

should actually be

```
$result = $this->mock->findWithSstAndBdc(30207, 10);
```

Also keep in mind you can mock an entire chain of calls (useful to fluent queries like this):

```
$this->mock->shouldReceive('where->whereHas->get')
     ->once()->andReturn(/*MAKE A FAKE OBJECT HERE*/);
```

I would also use PHP's built-in foreach() instead of using $factures->each as it is one less thing to test then.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.

As suggested I've tried replacing $this->repo with $this->mock but I'm now getting the following error:

BadMethodCallException: Method Mockery_0_FD_Repo_FactureSst_FactureSstInterface::findWithSstAndBdc() does not exist on this mock object

Answer (score 0):

Try like below

```
$this->mock
->shouldReceive('where->whereHas->get')
->once()->andReturn('Any desired data');

Hope this will work. Thanks.
```